# The View is not reading the current session

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

This is my servlet that creates the session and stores an accessCount to that current session

```
@WebServlet("/ShowSession.do")
public class ShowSession extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        String header;
        Integer accessCount  = (Integer)request.getAttribute("accessCount");

        if(accessCount == null){
            accessCount = new Integer(0);
            header = "Welcome New Comer";
        }else{
            header = "Welcome Back!";
            accessCount = new Integer(accessCount.intValue() + 1 );
        }

        //Integer is immutable data structure. so we cannot
        //modify the old one in-place,Instead, you have to
        //allocate a new one and redo setAttribute
        session.setAttribute("accessCount", accessCount);
        session.setAttribute("heading", header);
        RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/showsession.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And this is the View that prints out the contents of that session

```
<body>
    <%
        HttpSession clientSession = request.getSession();
        String heading = (String) clientSession.getAttribute("heading");
        Integer accessCount = (Integer) clientSession
                .getAttribute("accessCount");
    %>
    <h1>
        <center>
            <b><%=heading%></b>
        </center>
    </h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Info type</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td><%=clientSession.getId()%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Creation Time</td>
            <td><%=new Date(clientSession.getCreationTime())%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Time of last Access</td>
            <td><%=new Date(clientSession.getLastAccessedTime())%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number OF Access</td>
            <td><%=accessCount%></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

THe problem is that even though I already access for a lot of times it still returns me an accessCount == 0,

I am accessing at localhost:8080/someFolderName/ShowSession.do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting your `accessCount` initial value from the request. You should check it from session.

```
//Bad!
Integer accessCount  = (Integer)request.getAttribute("accessCount");
//Good (maybe)
Integer accessCount  = (Integer)session.getAttribute("accessCount");
```

Comment: OH SHOOT!! Good catch! used request rather than the session! thanks!

Comment: but wait, it is still returning null

Comment: It will return null the first time. Check the second time, and on and on. Also, make sure you're not setting the session variable again and/or cleaning the whole session.

Comment: but on my controller I've set to have a 0 value if its null

Comment: So you're just refreshing the page in order to make sure, right?

Comment: Okay the problem was, I was accessing the JSP(The Servlet did not past the request to JSP since I was accessing JSP therefore returning the value of null, so what I did was access the Servlet instead ) Thanks! :)